# You cannot search for the association field, because it is the inverse side of an association. Find methods only work on owning side associations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hey guys im trying to establish a relation between objects of the me same model.

I have a table `Qcm`,  a table `Equivalent` and last table is `EquivalentRelation`.
The idea is to have a QCM that can be related to many others QCM.

My `Equivalent` model is set up in a way with a variable `$qcmId` which is the id (int) of the qcm and a Primary Key of my `Equivalent` model.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EquivalentRepository::class)
 */
class Equivalent
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $qcmId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=EquivalentRelation::class, inversedBy="equivalent")
     */
    private $equivalentRelation;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getQcmId()
    {
        return $this->qcmId;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $qcmId
     */
    public function setQcmId($qcmId): void
    {
        $this->qcmId = $qcmId;
    }

    public function getEquivalentRelation(): ?EquivalentRelation
    {
        return $this->equivalentRelation;
    }

    public function setEquivalentRelation(?EquivalentRelation $equivalentRelation): self
    {
        $this->equivalentRelation = $equivalentRelation;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My `EquivalentRelation` model is set up with a `$equivalent` thats has a relation with my `Equivalent` model and a `$relateId` which is relation established with the chosen QCM im associating with.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EquivalentRelationRepository::class)
 */
class EquivalentRelation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Equivalent::class, mappedBy="equivalentRelation")
     */
    private $equivalent;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Qcm::class, inversedBy="equivalentRelations")
     */
    private $relatedId;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->equivalent = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->relatedId = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Equivalent[]
     */
    public function getEquivalent(): Collection
    {
        return $this->equivalent;
    }

    public function addEquivalent(Equivalent $equivalent): self
    {
        if (!$this->equivalent->contains($equivalent)) {
            $this->equivalent[] = $equivalent;
            $equivalent->setEquivalentRelation($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEquivalent(Equivalent $equivalent): self
    {
        if ($this->equivalent->removeElement($equivalent)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($equivalent->getEquivalentRelation() === $this) {
                $equivalent->setEquivalentRelation(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Qcm[]
     */
    public function getRelatedId(): Collection
    {
        return $this->relatedId;
    }

    public function addRelatedId(Qcm $relatedId): self
    {
        if (!$this->relatedId->contains($relatedId)) {
            $this->relatedId[] = $relatedId;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeRelatedId(Qcm $relatedId): self
    {
        $this->relatedId->removeElement($relatedId);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The next step was to have a `EquivalentType` form that would take the chosen QCM (can be multiple) and validate my model with ease. so far that part seems to be working without and issue.

```
class EquivalentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('relatedId', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Qcm::class,
            'choice_label' => 'id',
            'multiple' => true,
            'label' => 'QCM Ref Master',
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => EquivalentRelation::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

After sending my form everything works perfectly,

Handling the request thru  `QcmController` :

Since i have two different model that are related, i create first a new `Equivalent`.

```
$equivalent = new Equivalent();
$equivalent->setQcmId($qcm->getId());
```

followed by the same thing for EquivalentRelation

```
$equivalentrelation = new EquivalentRelation();
$equivalentrelation->addEquivalent($equivalent);
```

When trying to access the `EquivalentRelation` with equivalent as query parameter to display all the QCM (`relatedId`) object that are related it it.

```
$tester = $equivalentRepository->findBy(['qcmId' => $qcm->getId()]);
$data =  $equivalentRelationRepository->findBy(['equivalent' => $tester]);
```

here is the controller side of it :

```
      $equivalent = new Equivalent();
       $equivalent->setQcmId($qcm->getId());
       $equivalentrelation = new EquivalentRelation();
       $equivalentrelation->addEquivalent($equivalent);
        $equival = $this->createForm(EquivalentType::class, $equivalentrelation);
        $equival->handleRequest($request);
if ($equival->isSubmitted() && $equival->isValid()){
            $entityManager->persist($equivalent);
            $entityManager->persist($equivalentrelation);
            $entityManager->flush();
           return $this->redirectToRoute('qcm_show', ['id' => $qcm->getId()]);
        }
```

i get this error messages :

```
You cannot search for the association field 'App\Entity\EquivalentRelation#equivalent', because it is the inverse side of an association. Find methods only work on owning side associations.
```

I tried every method, i dont know if something is wrong with my deign or mapping system.

Comment: Please show your complete controller method(s) where you handle the form and where you use the repository to find the entities.

Comment: i added the controller side of it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to run that query as you already have the `Equivalent $tester` entity that you are checking for. Just use its getter method:

```
$tester = $equivalentRepository->findBy(['qcmId' => $qcm->getId()]);
//$data =  $equivalentRelationRepository->findBy(['equivalent' => $tester]);
$data =  $tester->getEquivalentRelation();
```

Comment: that does work but the output doesnt match the get method return null value. i tried with object that had relation and one that didnt the output is still the same.

Comment: Did you persist the relation?

Comment: yeah i did persist, the issue isnt my objects being saved. it is saved each time i send a form.